Is it a theorem of ZF that a non-empty countable Cartesian product of finite non-singleton sets has the cardinality of the continuum?
I think that, without countable choice, I can prove quite easily that for a sequence $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of sets $S_n$ with $|S_n|=2$, the Cartesian product $\,\prod_{n=1}^\infty S_n\,$ is either empty or else has the same cardinality as $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. Namely, if $\,\prod_{n=1}^\infty S_n\,$ is non-empty then we can take an element $(\tilde{s}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \prod_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ and then define the bijection
\begin{align*}
\prod_{n=1}^\infty S_n &\to \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} \\
(s_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} &\mapsto (\delta_{s_n \, , \, \tilde{s}_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}.
\end{align*}
But now my question is: Is it a theorem of ZF (without countable choice) that for any sequence $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of sets $S_n$ with $2 \leq |S_n| < \infty$, the Cartesian product $\,\prod_{n=1}^\infty S_n\,$ is either empty or else has the same cardinality as $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$?

I doubt it. Suppose $(X_n){n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of nonempty finite sets with empty product. Let $Y_n=X_1\times\cdots\times X_n$; then $(Y_n){n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of nonempty finite sets such that no infinite subsequence has nonempty product. Let $S_n=Y_n\cup{0}$; then $2\le|S_n|\lt\infty$ and $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}S_n$ is nonempty but can't have the cardinality of the continuum, being a countable union of finite sets.

@bof Really nice argument! Is it a theorem of ZF that a countable union of finite sets cannot have the cardinality of the continuum? (With countable choice it's easy to see that a countable union of finite sets is countable; but without countable choice, I don't know what happens.)

@bof Can you please explain why $\pi_{n\in\N} $ is a countable union of finite sets.

@JoelAdler Let $$P=\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}S_n$$. Then $$P=\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb N}{x\in P: x_n=0\text{ for all }n\gt m}$$ and $$|{x\in P: x_n=0\text{ for all }n\gt m}|=|S_1\times\cdots\times S_m|\lt\infty.$$

@bof: Clever, thank you!

@NoahSchweber Sorry, how do we know in ZF that there exists an injection from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$? [Every attempted construction that I can think of uses at least countable choice somewhere.]

@JulianNewman Let me rephrase (a finger-slip deleted my previous comment anyways). Let $X$ be a disjoint union of countably many finite sets, and suppose towards contradiction that $\vert X\vert=\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$. Then by definition there's an injection $X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Pulling back along this injection gives a family of orderings of the components of $X$, which lets the usual proof of countability go through. Put another way, a disjoint union of countably many finite sets can't inject into a linearly orderable set without being countable.

@NoahSchweber Great, thanks!

No. Take for instance a sequence of two-element sets $(A_i)_{i\in\omega}$ such that every infinite subsequence has empty product ("Russellian socks"), and let $B_i=A_i\sqcup\{\{i\}\}$. Then the product $\mathcal{B}$ of the $B_i$s is nonempty, but every element of $\prod\mathcal{B}$ is eventually the identity function. It's easy to check that this means $\vert\prod \mathcal{B}\vert\not=\mathfrak{c}$.
On the other hand, a nonempty product of an infinite sequence of two-element sets must have size continuum (fixing an element of the product gives a completely explicit bijection with $2^\omega$). Moreover, if $\mathcal{B}=(B_i)_{i\in\omega}$ is a sequence of three-element sets whose product is nonempty, then either $\prod\mathcal{B}$ bijects to the continuum or there is a sequence of two-element sets $\mathcal{A}=(A_i)_{i\in\omega}$ with $A_i\subset B_i$ and $\prod \mathcal{A}=\emptyset$ (fix $f\in\prod \mathcal{B}$ and let $A_i=B_i\setminus\{f(i)\}$).
Going out on a limb, I suspect that - at least if the finite sets have size bounded strictly below $\omega$ - either the product has size continuum or we can "embed a Russellian phenomenon" somehow. But I don't know how to state this precisely right now, let alone prove it.

Thanks. To clarify about the first bit: don't you need $(A_i)$ to have the property that the product of every infinite subsequence is empty [rather than just that the product of the entire sequence is empty], as exemplified in the construction in bof's comment under my question?

@JulianNewman Yes, that's quite right - I was sloppy. Fixed!
